# Connecting different Android project to an existing Google-Endpoints Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, backend, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working on an Android project that needs three versions of the same application (for example: Admin version, User version, Custom version). I have already created a Google-App-Engine endpoints backend in the User version of the app. I have to start working on the other two versions now and I want to connect these two versions to the backend I created in the User version. I have tried finding the answer to this on the internet but I haven't been successful in doing so. I believe it is possible to connect the other versions of the app to the backend by importing the endpoint libraries from the cloud into the android projects somehow but I haven't been able to find a way to do so yet.
I did come across a way to import an existing module in the Android project but if I do that, then any time when I make changes to the backend in the "User" version, I will have to re-import the module in other versions of the app. I am so lost and confused.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are all of your Android applications in the same Android Studio project?  If so I think you might be able to just add
    compile project(path: ':{yourBackendModuleGoesHere}', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
to each of your Android apps build.gradle.

You could probably also make it work even if your backend is in a separate AndroidStudio project as long as they're part of the same gradle build.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying.

The three apps are in different Androud Studio projects.

You've mentioned that I can make it work if all three apps are part of the same gradle build. Would you care to explain how can I do that?

Comment: I would recommend placing them all in the same project if you're working with them as one codebase.

If you want to combine them into the same gradle build (which you should only really do if all the modules are in the same src repo), you could take a look at the way an Android Studio project with multiple modules is configured.  Look at the build.gradle and settings.gradle in the project root and use that as a template for your parent directory. 

Then add 'compile project(path: ':backendModule', configuration: 'android-endpoints') to the android modules build.gradle.

Comment: Thanks again for replying! I cannot keep the apps in the same project. Think of my app as an application like Uber. They have a different app for riders, and drivers (and i assume they have one for admin too). Myapplication is similar to it which is why I have to keep my apps in different projects so I can separately install them as required. The drivers should install only the driver app and the riders should install only the riders app. So is there still a way to make all three apps to use the same app engine backend-endpoints module?

Comment: So be aware that an Android Studio project, and an Android application are two different things.  You can have multiple Android apps in the same Android Studio projects.  Each Android module you create is its own application that can be installed separately.  Does that help?

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks for the info! So how can I create a new app module in the project? Also, how can I install the modules separately?

Comment: Fortunately, I figured it out. Your answer definitely helped me. All I had to do was create another app in the same module. 
Thank you!

Comment: Although this may work in this context, the original question has not really been answered, I need to do the same thing, but I want to keep the backend separate to the front end, so that I can build on a CI server separately as I may want to make changes on the backend and leave the front end unchanged.

Comment: Could you simply add the generated client libraries from your backend manually to your android project's classpath?

Answer (score 0):

After you build your cloud module there is a YOUR_CLOUD_MODULE_NAME-android-endpoints.jar under YOUR_CLOUD_MODULE_NAME/build/libs.

You can copy this jar into libs directory of all your android projects that need to interact with your back-end.

This approach makes it really easy to get out of sync though.  After every change to back-end you would need to update the .jar in all dependent modules.